# How do I send a query string in post request in Python using pipe delimiters?

Tags: python, python-requests

The query string for the ASP page is sent by url?string=username|password
where string=username|password is urlencoded. I'm quite confused as to achieve this in Python Requests module. 
This is the url:

```
example.asp?options=2
```

with parameters `string=username|password`

basically, the "security" feature of the api during POST is that the parameters shouldn't show in the url.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @SimeonVisser Honestly, all I've is a requests.post('url',data=params) where params = {'username':'username','password':'password}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requests automatically urlencodes POSTed data: just provide it in a dictionary. The correct code is this:

```
>>> data = {'string': username + '|' + password}
>>> r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `requests.get()` function because when you request a url like what you have indicated, it use the **GET** http method.

I haven't encounted the situation that if the url like `url?string=username` uses a **POST** http method and if it does use **POST** method, then use `requests.post()` function like this:

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

Comment: But this doesn't help. It needs to delimited with a "|".